# In Azure DevOps pipelines, using variables in the powershell task results in ArgumentParseError when doing az login

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-service-principal

I have a Powershell task as such in my pipeline:

```
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      az login --service-principal --username $env:servicePrincipalId --password $env:servicePrincipalKey --tenant $env:tenantId
      python $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/the/path/to/my/python/script.py
  displayName: 'Execute Python code'
```

The service principal details are provided to me by having `addSpnToEnvironment: true` in an AzureCLI task prior to this Powershell task.

When the Powershell task runs, I get
`ArgumentParseError: argument --username/-u: expected one argument`. How can I resolve this?

Comment: shouldn't you be using $env: instead of $env. ?

Comment: Sorry, just realized I am indeed using $env: in my actual pipeline. Typed it out as $env. here on accident. Edited my question to reflect that.

Comment: What I find really helpful when troubleshooting these errors is to scatter a few of the following tasks around the pipeline (as variables are scoped so may not exist in all your tasks - depending on how you use stages, jobs etc..)                 

- pwsh: "Get-ChildItem env:"
  displayName: "Display Variables"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if the password value is started with the character '**`-`**'.

This is a known issue caused by the leading character '**`-`**' that makes the argument parser to confuse it as an option name. See [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/12105).

As a workaround, you can solve the issue by adding '`=`' between the option name and value.

```
az login --service-principal --username=$env:servicePrincipalId --password=$env:servicePrincipalKey --tenant=$env:tenantId
```

In addition, you also can try the following ways:

- This issue should have been fixed in the latest version of Azure CLI, you can try to upgrade the Azure CLI to the latest version on the agent machine.
- Try as **@Krzysztof Madej**'s suggestions that using the [Azure PowerShell task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-powershell?view=azure-devops), and setting the authorization via an [Azure Resource Manager service connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#sep-azure-resource-manager).

Comment: So I tried using this suggestion with @Krzysztof Madej 's suggestion of using Azure PowerShell. This does get me further, but now I get the following error: ```##[error]Failed to resolve tenant ''```.

Comment: When you created the **Azure Resource Manager service connection**, did you try using "**`Service principal (manual)`**" method? This method can allow you specify the Tenant and Service principal. Make sure you have filled with the correct **`Service Principal Id`**, **`Service principal key`** and **`Tenant ID`**.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend you to use [Azure PowerShell task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-powershell?view=azure-devops) which:

> Use this task to run a PowerShell script within an Azure environment. The Azure context is authenticated with the provided Azure Resource Manager service connection.

```
# Azure PowerShell
# Run a PowerShell script within an Azure environment
- task: AzurePowerShell@4
  inputs:
    #azureSubscription: Required. Name of Azure Resource Manager service connection
    #scriptType: 'FilePath' # Optional. Options: filePath, inlineScript
    #scriptPath: # Optional
    #inline: '# You can write your Azure PowerShell scripts inline here. # You can also pass predefined and custom variables to this script using arguments' # Optional
    #scriptArguments: # Optional
    #errorActionPreference: 'stop' # Optional. Options: stop, continue, silentlyContinue
    #failOnStandardError: false # Optional
    #azurePowerShellVersion: 'OtherVersion' # Required. Options: latestVersion, otherVersion
    #preferredAzurePowerShellVersion: # Required when azurePowerShellVersion == OtherVersion
```